# how to add and manage ROLES in FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I installed FOSUserBundle and i would like to add any additional role, such ROLE_NEW. In sfGuardUser just had to do

```
$this->getUser()->addCredential('new');
```

in action, and here?

Besides, how can I (admin) manage all (first of all manage ROLES) users? In sfGuardUser I had generated default admin page, and here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default FOSUserBundle manage roles as array, but you can use the concept of "Groups" for this purpose.

Read in docs https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/groups.md

And read some discussions about advantages and disadvantages 
[FOS bundle - How to select users with a specific role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/symfony-2-fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role)

Comment: i know this, but how can i in this example i can add user to group?

Comment: Tony, did you find out how?