# Is there a way to query if array field contains a certain value in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Starting out with Symfony2 + Doctrine.

I have a table with User objects (fos_user), for which my schema contains a *roles* column of an *'array'* type.

Doctrine saves fields of this type by serializing them from php 'array' to 'longtext' (in mysql's case).

So let's say I have the following users saved into DB:

```
User1: array(ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CUSTOM1)
User2: array(ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CUSTOM2)
User3: array(ROLE_CUSTOM2)
```

Now in my controller I want to select all users with ROLE_ADMIN set. 
Is there a way to write a DQL query which would directly return me *User1* and *User2*?
Or do I need to fetch all users to have Doctrine to unserialize roles column and then for each of them do **in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $user->getRoles())**?

I have searched the [DQL part of the manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), but so far did not find anything similar to my needs...

**UPD:** Found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/symfony-2-fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role) about the same thing which contains a working query code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use `LIKE` statement described in this manual (yes, even on serialized objects).

I'd suggest you to create an entity class for roles and join it with the user entity by *ManyToMany* association.

Comment: Indeed. This seems to be the only way. Found an existing question which has an exact query which works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/symfony-2-fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role. Using many-to-many would be an option if only I did not rely on the FOSUserBundle which stores roles in DB :)