# Doctrine where array field contains element

Tags: sql, arrays, doctrine, query-builder

I have an entity which has an `array` property:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="provinces", type="array")
 */
private $provinces;
```

How can I make a query to extract all the entities containing a specific element? Something like this:

```
$entities = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->where($qb->expr()->contains('e.provinces', ':element'))
    ->setParameter('element', $element)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to query if array field contains a certain value in Doctrine2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126220/is-there-a-way-to-query-if-array-field-contains-a-certain-value-in-doctrine2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to understand what the [Doctrine array type](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#array) represents, so basically the **Doctrine array type** translates into a **SQL text type** which is simply a serialized string. So you could create a query using the doctrine expression `like` so your query would look something like this

```
$entities = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->where($qb->expr()->like('e.provinces', ':element'))
    ->setParameter('element', '%' . \serialize($element) . '%')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

which is the equivalent for SQL `'SELECT ... WHERE e.provinces LIKE "%' . \serialize($element) . '%";'`

---

But because you included the [sql] tag in your question I would like to tell you that this is not the correct way to handle those kind of situations, your database violates the [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). In Web development it is usual thing to violate the normalization forms, you can see it done by Content Management Systems when they store configurations, but they do not try to query those configuration parameters. In your case, you wish to query for provinces so normally you should struggle to query indexed fields, to increase the performance of your queries.

So a solution could be creating a **Province Entity** and replacing the `array` type with a `ManyToMany` relation.

Comment: Thanks! Since the province code is a 2 characters string I can safely use your `LIKE` example.