# Doctrine: query array type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Doctrine can automatically serialize simple PHP array values (see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/types.html#array-types).

**Example**

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_table")
 */
class MyTable {
    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="my_array", type="json", nullable=true)
     */
    private $myArray;
}
```

**Example in database**

```
|   my_array    |
|---------------|
|'["FOO","BAR"]'|
```

**Question**

Is there a way to query these values without some sort of ugly regex directly by DQL or with query builder?

```
$queryBuilder
    ->andWhere(":searchParam IN myTable.myArray")
    ->setParameter('searchParam', 'FOO');
```

---

Side note: I could always wrap the `searchParam` and search with `LIKE` key word. However I am looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: What database system are we talking about? For example, PostgreSQL has [JSONB type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html), which can be nicely queried. I'm not familiar with MySQL but there's also [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html).

Comment: PostgresSql witch does has its own JSON type. But I am limited with what can Doctrine and its DQL do.

Comment: Right, that's why I don't use Doctrine :) Nevertheless, I believe that you can use [raw SQL with Doctrine](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html), but I'm not an expert on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such way. 
references:
[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126220/is-there-a-way-to-query-if-array-field-contains-a-certain-value-in-doctrine2)
[second](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1308)

Comment: Unfortunately true :-\ I am marking this as correct answer until Doctrine implements this.