# FOSuserBundle multiple types of users

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I started using FOSuserBundle and I would like to use their login functionality for all of my users: customers, admins, and affiliates.

Of course, there will be one main table that will contain all of the users data and then another table for each type.

The problem is how do I create different login forms on different pages and, of course, the register functionality is different.

I can't override controllers because I'm only allowed to override a bundle once in a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use different tables, login or registration forms.

These link will help you:

- [Using Groups With FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/groups.md)
- [Symfony 2 - FOS bundle - How to select users with a specific role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/symfony-2-fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role)

Comment: yes I saw that thanks, it may help with the group problem. but anyway I should table for customers for example because they need more fields like description, favorite color or whatever. how do I run over the register controller on several pages with different functionality?

Comment: In this case you need your own user provider, 'cause FOSUserBundle will not allow you to keep users by different entities. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html