# How to search an array of an entity in dql?

Tags: php, symfony, dql

I am trying to filter out admins that have a super admin role. Why is the following not working?

```
public function findAdmins()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('a')
        ->from('MyBundle:Admin', 'a')
        ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'a.roles'));

    $result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();

    return $result;
}
```

It will give me the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 68: Error: Expected Literal, got 'a'
```

The DQL-query looks like this:

```
SELECT a FROM MyBundle:Admin a WHERE ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN NOT IN(a.roles)
```

Role itself is not an entity. It is simply an array of strings.

```
$roles = array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN)'
```

Comment: is `a.roles` a collection you are joining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `MEMBER OF` operator

```
$qb
->select('a')
->from('MyBundle:Admin', 'a')
->where(':role NOT MEMBER OF ad.roles')->setParamete('role', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN');
```

**Update.**
The only solution found is to check serialized string in db with `LIKE`. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/symfony-2-fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role)

Comment: This is giving me the following error:

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 65 near 'roles': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a CollectionValuedAssociationField.

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/symfony-2-fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `column name` with `table name`

Try this,

```
$qb
    ->select('a')
    ->from('MyBundle:Admin', 'ad')
    ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'ad.roles'));
```

It should be like,

```
SELECT a FROM MyBundle:Admin ad WHERE ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN NOT IN(ad.roles)
```

Comment: The same error comes up:

    [Syntax Error] line 0, col 62: Error: Expected Literal, got 'ad'