# Search By Roles FOSu

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to collect all my users with (roles=ROLE_CHAUFFEUR) but i can't fin a way 
to get all 'chauffeurs'

```
class VehiculeForm extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('mat_vehicule')
                ->add('dateMiseCirculation')
                ->add('marquevehicule')
                ->add('marquevehicule', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'KiboTaxiUserBundle:UserKibo',
                    'property' => 'username',
                    'label' => 'Choisir:',
                    'query_builder' => function(UserKiboRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                ->where('u.roles  = a:1:{i:0;s:14:"ROLE_CHAUFFEUR";}  ');
                    },
                ))
                ->add('submit', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'Vehicule';
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is the same problem I supose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/symfony-2-fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role

Answer (score 1):

You have to query for your roles with LIKE like this:

```
$queryBuilder
->where("u.roles LIKE :role")
->setParameter("role", "%".$role."%");
```