# How to get a list of users with specific role symfony controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm new to symfony 2, working with FOSUserBundle along with PUGXMultiUserBundle and I have troubles retrieving the list of users with a specific role, for example : ROLE_ADMINISTRATEUR to notifiy them about something. Anyway, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role) this is my UserRepository class:

```
<?php
namespace OC\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
 public function findByRoles($role)
{
 $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
 $qb->select('u')
    ->from('OCUserBundle:User', 'u')
    ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
    ->setParameter('roles', '%"'.$role.'"%');

 return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
 }
}
```

and this is the code inside in the controller's action:

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository2=$em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:User');
$roles='ROLE_ADMINISTRATEUR';
$users=$repository2->findByRoles(array('roles'=>$roles));

Return $this->render('OCUserBundle:Default:test.html.twig',array(
        'users'=>$users));
```

and my test.html.twig page:

```
 {% for a in users %}
 {{a.username}}
 {% endfor %}
```

All what I get is an empty page. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: should I use the type column instead of the role column in the User Table?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't bother dealing with existing role hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Actually, using PUGXMultiUserBundle, you can select from a particular table, (you can associate a type of user with a role) so I changed the action inside the controller to this:

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository2=$em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:UserAdministrateur');
$admins=$repository2->findAll();

Return $this->render('OCUserBundle:Default:test.html.twig',array(
    'admins'=>$admins));
```

Works like a charm. HOpe this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I try to do this also without PUGXMultiUserBundle with the function:

```
$users = $repositoryUser->findByRoles("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN");
```

But it's doesn't work i get an empty array, so i do it manually:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u') ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u') ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles') ->setParameter('roles', '%"'."ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN".'"%');
$users = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Maybe this can help people who are in the same case of me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by correcting this line :

```
$users=$repository2->findByRoles(array('roles'=>$roles));
```

By :

```
$users=$repository2->findByRoles('ROLE_ADMINISTRATEUR');
```

?

Your method seems to search for users for ONE role. The LIKE condition expects a string and not an array.

The method would be then more like *findByRole()* and not *findByRoles()*.

Comment: changed to 
$repository2=$em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:User');
$users=$repository2->findByRoles('ROLE_ADMINISTRATEUR');

and in the UserRepository:

public function findByRoles($role)
{
    
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('u')
        ->from('OCUserBundle:User', 'u')
        ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
        ->setParameter('roles', '%"'.$role.'"%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

Nothinh happens, the page is still empty.

Comment: Did you try to debug the $users variable to see if there was anything inside ? Also, check if the SQL generated by the query ($qb->getSql() and $qb->getParameters()) seems fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem as the OP. Actually the thing with the above piece of code from the OP, are the double quotes: `->setParameter('roles', '%"'.$role.'"%');`
These didn't seemed right from the first look. Changed to: `->setParameter('roles', '%'.$role.'%');` and all works fine.