# How to use QueryBuilder and Doctrine Array type?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a user table with a property named roles, which is in Doctrine array type. This is how it looks like in the database :
[roles in user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgqOl.png)

I am creating a query using Doctrine class QueryBuilder.
Right now, my query looks like this :

```
    $queryBuilder->select(array("u.id", "u.roles"))
        ->from("CNDUserBundle:User", "u")
        ->setMaxResults(10)
    ;
```

I need to get a list of all the users with a specific role, but I don't know how to check the value inside the Doctrine array type.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role) to a similar question

Comment: So the only solution seems to be using the LIKE statement. I thought Doctrine implemented some method to use the array type. Thank you !

Comment: You can use IN, that check if a value is in an array of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $queryBuilder->select(array("u.id", "u.roles"))
    ->from("CNDUserBundle:User", "u")
    ->where('u.role IN (:role)')
    ->setParameter("role",array(1,2,3))
    ->setMaxResults(10)
;
```

something like that