# FOSUserBundle & Users Roles

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

here is my code to retreive users from db :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    $qb->select('c.username')
        ->where('c.username LIKE :term')
        ->setParameter('term', '%' . $term . '%')
        ->where('c.roles LIKE :role')
        ->setParameter('role', '%"ROLE_COM"%');

    $arrayAss = $qb->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

I want to select only users with the admin role and nothing works.

thaks for helping

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOS bundle - How to select users with a specific role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role)

Comment: Thnaks for the url i didnot found it. ive edited the code but it seems that i cant do it with 2 parameters in each line i must combine them into one line. Loot top for code

Comment: you need to use `andWhere` and not `where` so that the where clauses can stack

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly :) Add an answer to close this

Answer (score 0):

Try with `isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')` method.

For further information about this method: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved this way :

```
        $qb->select('c.username')
        ->where('c.username LIKE :term AND c.roles LIKE :role')
        ->setParameter('term', '%' . $term . '%')
        ->andWhere('c.roles LIKE :role')
        ->setParameter('role', '%"ROLE_COM"%')
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The role param should not have quotes and the second "where" should be "andWhere". Try it like this it should work.

```
$qb->select('c.username')
    ->where('c.username LIKE :term')
    ->setParameter('term', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->andWhere('c.roles LIKE :role') // andWhere for second conditional
    ->setParameter('role', '%ROLE_COM%'); // Lose the quotes here.

$arrayAss = $qb->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult();
```