# Doctrine SELECT in array type

Tags: php, sql, arrays, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with a project and `array` type in doctrine. 
My entity got the field userslist who save list of user id. In my DB the field type is TEXT :

```
/**
 * @Column(type="array", nullable=false)
 */
private $userslist;
```

I create my content like this :

`$r->createNewLine(50, 'Name', 'Content', array(1, 5, 8))`

The result in my table for my field userslist look,like this (I think it's key -> value) :

```
a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:8;}
```

I used QueryBuilder to get the results, here is my request :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
->andWhere('r.userslist IN (:userid)')
->setParameters(array('userid' => array(1)));

return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

I always got an empty array as result.
I have several lines in my table with userid 1 in userslist field.

```
a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:8;}
a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:8;}
a:3:{i:0;i:9;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:2;}
a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:8;}
a:3:{i:0;i:9;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:2;}
...
```

I also tried to use an expression :

```
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('r.userslist', array(':userid')));
```

The result is also empty. 
But when I use `LIKE` it's working but not secure because I'm confuse between key and value in my table :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->andWhere("r.userslist LIKE :userid")
   ->setParameters(array('userid' => '%i:1;%'));
```

How can I get my lines where the userid 1 is in my userslist field ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine requires you to parse the entire string to find a direct match, other wise it appears you need to use the LIKE comparison to find a record based upon a selection of the data. Here is a similar question [FOS bundle - How to select users with a specific role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role)

To avoid this issue have you considered creating another entity and creation a relationship between that and your user object so that you don't have to rely on a LIKE condition to find your data.

Comment: If I want to use the LIKE function, I need to send array(1 => 1, 5 => 5) when I create my line. So I could use `i:1;i:1;`, but it's not really clean for me...

Comment: Are you only going to be searching for one user id at a time or do you need to check for multiple ids in the list to find a record?

Comment: Only One user at a time

Comment: Trying changing the type to simple array, if you ids are always unique you can run a like looking for just the value and not have to worry about finding the key, as it only uses a delimiter to split the values. Check here for more detail http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#simple-array