# Get users by role

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an array of entities (groups) in an entity (user), and in my Query Builder I would like to retrieve users by role.

I'm trying with this:

```
public function findUsersByRole($role){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->select('u')
       ->where('u.roles LIKE :role')
       ->setParameter('role', $role);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But I don't get results.

I tried also:

```
public function findUsersByRole($role)
{
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
  $qb->select('u')
      ->where(':role MEMBER OF u.roles')
      ->setParameter('role', $role);
  return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 62 near 'roles': Error: Invalid
> PathExpression. Must be a CollectionValuedAssociationField.

What am I doing wrong?

The roles are stored in the user table field roles field that is of JSON type, like this:

```
[
    "ROLE_USER",
    "ROLE_ADMIN"
]
```

This is the function of the **User class** that stores the user role in the database:

```
public function setRoles(array $roles){
    $this->roles = $roles;
}
```

This is the unit test I'm writing to test the **testFindUsersByRole** function:

```
public function testFindUsersByRole() {
    $user1 = $this->createUser(1, "Developer", "John", "Smith", "smith@test.com");
    $user2 = $this->createUser(2, "Developer", "Joe", "Black", "joe@test.com");
    $user3 = $this->createUser(3, "Developer", "Jack", "Blade", "blade@test.com");

    $roles1 = ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'];
    $roles2 = ['ROLE_USER'];

    $user1->setRoles($roles1);
    $user2->setRoles($roles2);

    $response = $this->userRepository->findUsersByRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    $this->assertCount(1, $response);

    $this->purge([$user1, $user2, $user3]);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which data type does that `roles` column use? And if you want to run a `LIKE` search, is there any reason to skip wildcards?

Comment: aren't roles sotred in json? there should be ways to search in them in DQL

Comment: I have added to my question some more details about how the users are stored. They are stored as an array, not as a JSON.

Comment: You are right, I have checked the data type of the column and it's JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FOS bundle - How to select users with a specific role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role)

Comment: I tried with the suggested solution from this previous answer but  I'm not using FOS groups. And the first solution suggested returns no results.

Comment: My case is different because in the case of that question the role field was serialised in this way {i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";i:1;s:9:"ROLE_USER";}

Comment: there is an extension that woks with MySQL 5.7+ [DoctrineJsonFunctions](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong.
In my unit test I was not saving the users entities on the database after assigning them the roles.
So I have fixed the unit test like this.

```
public function testFindUsersByRole() {
    $user1 = $this->createUser(1, "Developer", "John", "Smith", "smith@test.com");
    $user2 = $this->createUser(2, "Developer", "Joe", "Black", "joe@test.com");
    $user3 = $this->createUser(3, "Developer", "Jack", "Blade", "blade@test.com");

    $roles1 = ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'];
    $roles2 = ['ROLE_USER'];

    $user1->setRoles($roles1);
    $user2->setRoles($roles2);

    $this->entityManager->persist($user1);
    $this->entityManager->persist($user2);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    $response = $this->userRepository->findUsersByRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    $this->assertCount(1, $response);

    $this->purge([$user1, $user2, $user3]);
}
```

This function then is the one that worked:

```
public function findUsersByRole($role){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->select('u')
       ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
       ->setParameter('roles', '%"'.$role.'"%');
    
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
```